# Image Magick - import SVG file with layers

Tags: image-processing, svg, imagemagick, imagick

Is it possible to import an PSD or SVG file into Image Magick, and keep its layers?

For example, I would like to keep:
Text layer editable and
Shadow/overlay layer separate

Comment: Can you provided an example image, and expected results?

Comment: Sure, thanks!

I have an Image Magick admin/backend on my Wordpress Website, set up like this were I have separate layers:

https://gyazo.com/ddf0089c20fce18636223788ebe822eb

Questions:

- Is it possible to import a PSD or SVG file and have it with separate layers on my ImageMagick Admin/Wordpress backend? Or do I need to individually save them as images and import them one by one?

Can I import a displacement map profile I created on Photoshop and have it on one of these layers?